# Is there a term for words which falsely appear to be related etymologically?

Tags: terminology, etymology

I was doing research into the use of axes in Japanese martial arts. I discovered that the common name for this tool os "ono." I then discovered that is has another name, "masa-kari."

If I were to mispronounce this word in English, it would be very close to sounding like massacre.

So I looked up the etymology for massacre. It seems to come from French, and they seem to have gotten it from Latin (around the 1500's).

> 1575-85; (noun) < Middle French massacre, noun derivative of
>   massacrer, Old French maçacrer, macecler, probably < Vulgar Latin
>   *matteūcculāre, verbal derivative of *matteūca mallet (see mashie, mace1); (v.) < Middle French massacrer

There appears to be no link between massacre and masa-kari. Though I would expect one. Why?

Because of the similarities between maces and axes.

I can accept they are not related etymologically. What I am curious about is, are there words that appear in multiple languages, that appear related, but have no connection to each other?

Is there a term for this phenomena? Yes, I get statistics, and random chance. I'm not asserting magic, or divine intervention. I'm trying to asses this using scientific method.

If anything I have stated is inaccurate, I apologize please correct me. I am no expert in this field, and I do not claim any expertise.

Comment: It's usually called **chance similarity**. Campbell mentioned that "5-6 percent of the vocabulary of **any two compared languages** may be accidentally similar." Ringe 1992 discussed it in more detail, *On Calculating the Factor of Chance in Language Comparison*.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know if there was a magical term, like homonym means to words spelled the same, but different meanings and pronunciations (sometimes).

Comment: ["False friend {of a translator}"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) also seems to be related

Comment: I think what I am asking about appears to have more in common with "false cognates." If that's true, it's likely the "term" I was after.

Comment: Yes [false cognate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate) is the correct term. 'False friend' has a somewhat different meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just wanted to clarify things.

False cognates are words that exhibit chance similarity (or chance resemblance).

> The phenomenon is known as chance similarity, or chance resemblance. Words exhibiting this phenomenon are known as false cognates.

[Trask 2000](http://www.euppublishing.com/book/9780748610037):

[image]

Comment: Since you found the docs to support it, you get the points. Thank you.

Comment: Not related in any way?  Devoid of interest?  List those probabilities...